# Adding QgsLayoutItemTextTable to Print Layout

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, pyqgis-3

I am writing a script that automatically generates a print layout. In addition to the map, the print layout should contain a table with results of a series of calculations that I have in the form of a python dictionary. While I have gotten into the workflow of adding layout items to the print layout, `QgsLayoutItemTextTable` seems to work differently.

This works fine:

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()

title = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
title.setText('MyTitle')
title.adjustSizeToText()
layout.addLayoutItem(title)
```

The `QgsLayoutItemTextTable` class, however, is for some reason not based on the `QgsLayoutItem` class and therefore

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()

table = QgsLayoutItemTextTable(layout)
table.addRow(['hello', 'world', '!'])
layout.addLayoutItem(table)
```

results in the following error:

> TypeError: QgsLayout.addLayoutItem(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsLayoutItemTextTable'

Can anyone explain to me why this is the case and what is the intended workflow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case to add a table the method is not the same. You need add using this [addMultiFrame()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayout.html#a4cc19a7b428eaf740807e1098a864135) because **QgsLayoutItemTextTable** inherits from **QgsLayoutMultiFrame**:

```
layout.addMultiFrame(table)
```

**Minimum sample:**

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()

table = QgsLayoutItemTextTable(layout)
layout.addMultiFrame(table)

# Add columns       
cols = [QgsLayoutTableColumn(),QgsLayoutTableColumn(),QgsLayoutTableColumn()]
cols[0].setHeading("heading 0")
cols[1].setHeading("heading 1")
cols[2].setHeading("heading 2")
table.setColumns(cols)

# Add only 1 row
table.setContents([['hello', 'world', '!']])

# Base class for frame items, which form a layout multiframe item.
frame = QgsLayoutFrame(layout, table)
frame.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(30, 30), True)
table.addFrame(frame)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer! Unfortunately, just swapping this one line did not work for me. I don't get an error anymore but the table is still not added to the print layout. Could you please extent your answer to a complete minimum example workflow?

Comment: Added a minimum example

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! This example should find it's way into the [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html)

Comment: Your welcome!I will add it these days there