# Creating table coordinates of selected feature and adding it to layout with PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, print-composer, table, layouts

I am working on a Plugin that allows users to look for a feature in the database, select it, and then open the Layout designer with map, arrow legend and some labels.

I am looking to add a table that contains the selected feature coordinates if someone could help.

I already tried the code given here: [Adding QgsLayoutItemTextTable to Print Layout](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330120/adding-qgslayoutitemtexttable-to-print-layout)

Once the script executed, the Layout designer opened and QGIS crashes and shut down

***NB :** When I delete the last line, the layout is created. But when I open it manualy. QGIS crashes.*

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()

table = QgsLayoutItemTextTable(layout)
layout.addMultiFrame(table)

# Add columns       
cols = [QgsLayoutTableColumn(),QgsLayoutTableColumn(),QgsLayoutTableColumn()]
cols[0].setHeading("heading 0")
cols[1].setHeading("heading 1")
cols[2].setHeading("heading 2")
table.setColumns(cols)

#Add only 1 row
table.setContents([['hello', 'world', '!']])

#Base class for frame items, which form a layout multiframe item.
frame = QgsLayoutFrame(layout, table)
frame.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(30, 30), True)
table.addFrame(frame)
# Open the layout designerfor preview
iface.openLayoutDesigner(layout)
```

---

After I deleted the ***#Add columns*** section from the code below :

the frame is added and the layout designer opened
But the frame is shrinked and the row isn't displayed.
[image]

Comment: It looks like a bug. What is QGIS full version, like QGIS 3.xx.x ?

Comment: You create a LayoutFrame from a table, and then add the frame to the table (which is already in the frame)? Is that right?

Comment: I use QGIS 3.10 A Corunia...
I went step by step through the script and find out that the code line[table.setColumns(cols)] caused the crash...
the frame is drawn correctly if I delete that Code line...
I found out that the Class QgsLayoutItemTextTable has no attribute ".setColumn"...
Still looking for a clue...
Thx for all

Comment: Your script works as expected in QGIS v3.18.1.

Comment: Thank you, I just upgraded to the last version of QGIS 3.18.2. It's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @KadirŞahbaz. It was question of upgrading to newest version of QGIS.

[image]

Comment: What is the name of this Plugin? I want to try it when it will be released.